# Creating new rows in excel with From and To values

Tags: excel, function, formula

I currently have a sheet with two columns - 'From' and 'To'. I am trying to create a spreadsheet where each line is an individual value that falls within the ranges currently in each row.

An example (sorry I cannot embed images yet)--

**What I have:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

Comment: I see you added the function tag, can you post the code for your function?

Comment: You might need vba to do this. With just formulas, it will be difficult

Answer (score 2):

Try this VBA code,

```
Sub splitToCodes()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
j = 2
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1)) Then
        For k = Cells(i, 1) To Cells(i, 2)
            Cells(j, 4) = k
            j = j + 1
        Next k
    Else
        For k = Right(Cells(i, 1), Len(Cells(i, 1)) - 1) To Right(Cells(i, 2), Len(Cells(i, 2)) - 1)
            Cells(j, 4) = k
            Cells(j, 4) = Left(Cells(i, 1), Len(Cells(i, 1)) - Len(Cells(j, 4))) & k
            j = j + 1
        Next k
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

This code loops through the columns A and B and prints the output in column D. Modify as per your needs.

Note:- This code will work only for similar data as in the image as you have not mentioned any other format.

Comment: Beat me to it. I'm still going to post my solution because I honestly found it kind of challenging

Comment: Hi Gowtham, I was really puzzled by how to get the values for `A0082` in there, etc, will your code work for any variation of `A0000` to `A9999`? I had to do some kind of work around where I took a string of zeroes and took as many from it as I needed.

Comment: @dwirony I unstringed the 'A' part from the text and looped it. So it should work

Answer (score 1):

Copy & paste FROM and TO columns under each other and apply remove duplicates function at data block of menu bar.

Comment: Issue is when I have From A0001 to A0022. I need A0002, A0003, ... , A0022. Trying to see if there is a way to do it using an excel funtion instead of manually

Comment: @zcaad9 You are misusing the word "function". What you need for this is a **macro**.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my super tedious solution:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Long, sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, missingzeroes As Integer, zeroesholder As String, myzeroes As String
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If IsNumeric(Range("B" & i).Value) = True And IsNumeric(Range("A" & i).Value) = True Then
        j = Range("B" & i).Value - Range("A" & i).Value
        lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            For k = 0 To j
                Range("D" & lastrow + 1 + k).Value = Range("A" & i).Value + k
            Next k
    Else
        j = Right(Range("B" & i).Value, 4) - Right(Range("A" & i).Value, 4)
            lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            For k = 0 To j
                Range("D" & lastrow + 1 + k).Value = Left(Range("B" & i).Value, 1) & Right(Range("A" & i).Value, 4) + k
                If Len(Range("B" & i).Value) <> Len(Range("D" & lastrow + 1 + k).Value) Then
                    missingzeroes = Len(Range("B" & i).Value) - Len(Range("D" & lastrow + 1 + k).Value)
                    zeroesholder = "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                    myzeroes = Left(zeroesholder, missingzeroes)
                    Range("D" & lastrow + 1 + k).Value = Left(Range("A" & i).Value, 1) & myzeroes & Right(Range("A" & i).Value, Len(Range("D" & lastrow + 1 + k).Value) - 1) + k
                End If
            Next k
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]